# Stronglifts 5x5 related question

Tags: strength, strength-training, stronglifts

What are the accessories that you add with stronglifts and why?

As given on the website, I added chins and dips; reverse crunches(or hanging leg raises) and crunches; barbell curls and skullcrushers; and 10 minutes of HIIT cardio.

This is how my routine looks like now:

A. Squat(5x5), Bench(5x5), T-bar row(5x5), Weighted dips(3 sets), Skullcrusher(3 sets), Abs, Cardio

B. Squat(5x5), Overhead Press(5x5), Deadlift(1x5), Weighted Chins(3 sets), Curls(3 sets), Abs, Cardio

As I mentioned earlier, for abs, I perform one of either crunches, or leg raise, or reverse crunches.

Cardio: 5 rounds of 45 seconds treadmill and 15 seconds off. 5 rounds of 45 seconds step up step down(unsure of the proper name, it is like I would step my right leg, and then left, and then step down my right leg, followed by left leg, in a fast motion) and 15 seconds off.

Am I missing any body parts? If yes, what would be your suggestions, since I want to work towards being stronger, as well as looking good and symmetrical? (I have changed my routine [from this one](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/38149/is-this-a-good-split-made-my-own-template))

Answer (score 1):

A quick point worth mentioning... Stronglifts 5x5 is NOT a bodybuilding program. It is designed to build functional strength by using compound body movements.

Stronglifts is not the right plan if you are going toward a 'bodybuilding' physique (six pack and abs etc...), your focus is not on building (hypertrophy) individual body parts (the attention to detail that usually comes with bodybuilding rather than strength training)

5x5 will generally create a more 'block' like body shape due to the nature of the exercises.

I'm not saying this in any way to discourage you, I did stronglifts 5x5 for some time and throughly enjoyed it and made good progress. However, I am telling you this in order to realistically manage your expectations.

In terms of your actual plan, it seems it is suitable for hitting most of your body.

Comment: Thanks for the response, mate. I just want to look athletic and be functionally stronger . I mean I don't have to be very aesthetic

Comment: "'block' like"? It's not going to turn you into Spongebob Squarepants, and a strength program like StrongLifts or Starting Strength is definitely the right plan if you are a previously untrained individual looking for attain a bodybuilding physique, simply because it will be far better at build a decent strength base from which you can specialise into different areas like bodybuilding training. Going straight into a body part split program is likely to be highly suboptimal for a novice. (Not that the question mentioned training for bodybuilding.)